# Executing shell script with Pexpect.spawn()

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pexpect

My existing shell script "installation.sh" need user inputs as part of installation and I am trying to handle it with python pexpect.spwan(), However after executing script, it always stays in pexpect.spawn() process becuase script never ends and not able to match any user input. Is there better way to handle it ? appreciate response.

```
child = pexpect.spawn ('/opt/scripts/installation.sh')
for line in child:
    print(line.decode().strip())
child.expect('\r\n')

print(child.expect('Do you need to configure DNS? y\|n \[n\] '))
print(line.decode().strip('\n'))
child.sendline('y\n')

child.expect('Input IP address of DNS server:')
print(line.decode().strip('\n'))
child.sendline('10.11.11.13\n')

child.expect('Do you need to configure more DNS servers?')
child.sendline('n')
```

Comment: I've never used pexpect.  However, I would guess the `Do you need to configure DNS` line is never matched because it's already been consumed by the `for line in child` loop...

Comment: i never know we can write `for line in pexpect.spawn(...)`. just tried and it'll wait until the spawned process exits so the `for` loop in your script would block.

Comment: thank you for response, pexpect.spawn process is invoking installation.sh script and 'for loop' is printing each line. 'for loop' close statement is not there and child.close() can end loop. However that didnt work either.  'installation.sh' once invoked , it is waiting input from user and expect statement is waiting 'installation.sh' script to finish first before it matches or send the next command. that't what it appears to me , thank you again for responding to it.